# WCF async method calling hangs up?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

We have a WCF service with methods and their asyncs, we want to call them async.
The following code hangs up:

```
private void btnRunTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<List<DtoEmployee>> resultOfLoadEmployees = LoadEmployeesAsync(predicateEmployee1); // hangs up on this line
    resultOfLoadEmployees.Wait();
    var employeeList = resultOfLoadEmployees.Result;
    foreach (var item in employeeList)
    {
        //Do Something
    }           
}   
private async Task<List<DtoEmployee>> LoadEmployeesAsync(int employeeNumber)
{
    return await _serviceClient.EmployeeGetListAsync(employeeNumber);
}
```

but the following code is OK and runs without a problem:

```
private async Task<List<DtoEmployee>> LoadEmployeesAsync(int employeeNumber)
{
    return await _serviceClient.EmployeeGetListAsync(employeeNumber);
}


private async void btnRunTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<DtoEmployee> employeeList = await LoadEmployeesAsync(employeeNumber);
    foreach (var item in employeeList)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

What's the differences and which one is correct to call async WCF method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the differences and which one is correct to call async WCF
>   method?

That difference is that the former **deadlocks** here:

```
resultOfLoadEmployees.Wait();
```

A synchronization context is trying to marshal the continuation work back (everything after your first `await`) but can't because it's blocked via a `Wait()` call, which synchronously blocks. The latter properly asynchronously waits on the result to return, while not blocking the call. That's why [you shouldn't block no async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

You should use the latter.

Side note - you can save yourself the state-machine generation as you can simply return the hot task created by `EmployeeGetListAsync`:

```
private Task<List<DtoEmployee>> LoadEmployeesAsync(int employeeNumber)
{
    return _serviceClient.EmployeeGetListAsync(employeeNumber);
}
```

Comment: The "resultOfLoadEmployees.Result" doesn't help things either.

Comment: @BigDaddy Definitely. Although, `Wait` already kills it first.